# How to create expanding div width on hover

Tags: jquery, css, animation, html

Hi I want to create the expanding box animation featured on this site, specifically the way that the coloured div expands over the image and reveals more text.

http://metcreative.com/demo_viewer/index.php?theme=shocoonwp

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Well he gave you a correct response, but didn't give you all of the information that was needed.

I made a new fiddle wrapping it in both DIVs. What you should do, on the 'outer div', make the image you want as the background.  Then on the inner div, the content div.

Here is the Fiddle.  [Hover Div Image Box JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xkLng/1/)  Enjoy & Happy Coding.

Hit the up arrow if you are satisfied.

**css**

```
#outside {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    background: url("http://www.nyewall.com/images/2013/09/download-windows-7-hd-wallpapers-full-size-desktoplist.jpg") center center no-repeat;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#inside {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    background:#fff;
    opacity: .75;
    float: right;
    transition:width 2s;
    -webkit-transition:width 2s; /* Safari */
}
#inside:hover {
    width:300px;
}
```

**html**

```
<div id="outside">
    <div id="inside">
        Inside Div
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try with css3 like this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/M3AmL/)

CSS

```
    div {
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        background:red;
        transition:width 2s;
        -webkit-transition:width 2s;
        /* Safari */
    }
    div:hover {
        width:300px;
    }
```

HTML

```
 <div></div>
```